# What is the proper way to deal with conditional response in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have just started learning spring web flux. and there is complete change or perspective of how to do the 
work in reactive programming instead of imperative programming.

So, i would like to achieve a very simple output.

I have response class with fields success, message and List data.

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Response {

    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private List data;
}
```

and a Request class

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class LoginRequest {

    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

I also have userRepository with webFlux.

```
Mono<User> findUserByEmail(String email);
```

and i have a login action like this.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public Mono<Response> login(@RequestBody Mono<LoginRequest> request) {
}
```

Now i have to return response based on what userRepository gave me.

- It could return null if no user is present
- It could give me User class object if user is found
- now i have to check if password matches with the password given in LoginRequest

So I have to change response based on User repository
like if user not found

- I have to return response with success = false and message = "No user found"
  if user found with invalid password
- I have to return response with success = false and message = "invalid password"
  and if everything is good then
- I have to return success = true , message = "Welcome", and List with username,email etc.

I have tried lot of ways but at the end i failed to achieve this.

Comment: Question: Are you doing this merely as a learning exercise to become more familiar with reactive programming?

Comment: Yes i am learning reactive programing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a Mono as your argument to your controller, you can accept the value after standard data binding from Spring. Check the Spring docs for examples: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller

You also shouldn't get null from your repo, if the user can't be found you'll get an empty Mono (so `.map`, `.filter`, etc won't be called). That being the case, you can use `.switchIfEmpty` as replacement for null checking.

If you get data you can simply `.map` it to what you need since you don't need to block for any other data:

```
public Mono<Response> login(LoginRequest request) {
        return repo.findUserByEmail(request.getEmail())
            .map(user ->
                Objects.equals(request.getPassword(), user.getPassword())
                    ? new Response(true, "Welcome", Collections.emptyList())//populate list here
                    : new Response(false, "invalid password", Collections.emptyList()))
            //user wasn't found in the repo
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new Response(false, "No user found", Collections.emptyList())));
    }
```

Comment: why not just `user.getPassword().equals(request.getPassword())`?

Comment: just one more thing if i get Mono<User> inside map so its fine or should i do that in flatmap

Comment: if you are returning `Mono<user>` from a map then don't use map. use flatmap. otherwise the final return will be `Mono<Mono<User>>` if you are able to return just User then use map, the user will be automatically wrapped under a Mono.

Comment: If user.getPassword() is null you'll get an NPE. Objects.equals() avoids that trap.

Comment: Use .flatMap() whenever you'd end up with nested 'containers' such as Mono, Flux, Optional, Stream, etc.

Comment: Also note there are Mono.flatMapMany() and Flux.single() to avoid nesting between those types.